# How can I do a wildcard search for a dict of jsons?

Tags: python

Given this data:

```
gics_json = """
     {'Trading Companies & Distributors': [{'': '460',
       'CIK': '1067701',
       'Date first added': '2014-09-20',
       'Founded': '1997',
       'GICS Sector': 'Industrials',
       'GICS Sub-Industry': 'Trading Companies & Distributors',
       'Headquarters Location': 'Stamford, Connecticut',
       'SEC filings': 'reports',
       'Security': 'United Rentals, Inc.',
       'Symbol': 'URI'}],
     'Trucking': [{'': '262',
       'CIK': '728535',
       'Date first added': '2015-07-01',
       'Founded': '1961',
       'GICS Sector': 'Industrials',
       'GICS Sub-Industry': 'Trucking',
       'Headquarters Location': 'Lowell, Arkansas',
       'SEC filings': 'reports',
       'Security': 'J. B. Hunt Transport Services',
       'Symbol': 'JBHT'},
      {'': '351',
       'CIK': '878927',
       'Date first added': '2019-12-09',
       'Founded': '1934',
       'GICS Sector': 'Industrials',
       'GICS Sub-Industry': 'Trucking',
       'Headquarters Location': 'Thomasville, North Carolina',
       'SEC filings," "reports',
       'Security': 'Old Dominion Freight Line',
       'Symbol': 'ODFL'}]} """

gics_dict = json.loads(gics_json)
```

I want to find the GICS Sector/Sub-Industry section that's related to a search term.

For example, if I search for `Dominion`, I want to see:

```
   'GICS Sector': 'Industrials',
   'GICS Sub-Industry': 'Trucking'
```

I have been struggling, here's my (not working code):

```
    def searcher(value, yourdict):
      for key in yourdict:
          if value.lower() in yourdict[key]:
              print(yourdict[key][value])
searcher('dominion', gics_dict)
```

But I get no results. Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have not debugged your code. I would suggest using `print()` debugging. You could add `print(key)` just before the `if` line. That would show you all the keys that are being processed.

Comment: Why are you calling a string `gics_dict`? And what's a "dict of jsons"?

Comment: @KellyBundy good catch, sorry when I copied the code I forgot to include the process to convert it to dict - I use json module then json.loads(gics_json)

Comment: The input is not in json format. json requires double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make slight syntactic changes to `gics_dict`, but assuming this is what you get from `json.loads(gics_json)`, then there are quite a few modifications needed to `searcher()` to drill down into the structure:

```py
gics_dict = {'Trading Companies & Distributors': [{'': '460',
       'CIK': '1067701',
       'Date first added': '2014-09-20',
       'Founded': '1997',
       'GICS Sector': 'Industrials',
       'GICS Sub-Industry': 'Trading Companies & Distributors',
       'Headquarters Location': 'Stamford, Connecticut',
       'SEC filings': 'reports',
       'Security': 'United Rentals, Inc.',
       'Symbol': 'URI'}],
     'Trucking': [{'': '262',
       'CIK': '728535',
       'Date first added': '2015-07-01',
       'Founded': '1961',
       'GICS Sector': 'Industrials',
       'GICS Sub-Industry': 'Trucking',
       'Headquarters Location': 'Lowell, Arkansas',
       'SEC filings': 'reports',
       'Security': 'J. B. Hunt Transport Services',
       'Symbol': 'JBHT'},
      {'': '351',
       'CIK': '878927',
       'Date first added': '2019-12-09',
       'Founded': '1934',
       'GICS Sector': 'Industrials',
       'GICS Sub-Industry': 'Trucking',
       'Headquarters Location': 'Thomasville, North Carolina',
       'SEC filings': 'reports',
       'Security': 'Old Dominion Freight Line',
       'Symbol': 'ODFL'}]}


def searcher(value, yourdict):
    vl = value.lower()
    found = []
    for area in yourdict:
        for cik in yourdict[area]:
          for key in cik:
              if vl in cik[key].lower():
                  found.append(cik)
    for cik in found:
        print(cik['CIK'])
        print(f"'GICS Sector': {cik['GICS Sector']}")
        print(f"'GICS Sub-Industry': {cik['GICS Sub-Industry']}")
    
    #return found

searcher('dominion', gics_dict)
```

Output:

```
878927
'GICS Sector': Industrials
'GICS Sub-Industry': Trucking
```

Note that I suggest, from a design point of view, that you remove the for loop with the printing and add in `return found` and make another function do any required printing.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked.

I'm trying to learn and am interested in your design comment. Why is it better to have another function do the printing?

Comment: Your function searcher() should do one thing and do it well. It should also be testable. Then you would be able to use it by calling it from another function in the future. For example a function which prints the results.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and I'll adjust this function while also implementing this idea in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use
`if value.lower() in yourdict[key].lower():`
it should work

Comment: Please don't make suggestions that `should work`. You should run the code yourself.